# Google Drive API service not returning md5Checksum field

Tags: php, google-drive-api

i'm currently doing a script that returns all the files IDs on my drive. It works perfectly, but I'd like now to return an md5 of theses files. I saw on the metada doc page that the API can return a MD5, instead of downloading the file, and making an MD5 of the content.
To see the meatadata of a file, I have this : (I'm in PHP)

```
$file = $service->files->get($artwork_id, array());
```

I tried to fill the parameters array with arguments, but I can't get this field. Here is a screen of the result in my browser :
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out after trying multiple things. Here is the solution :

```
$file = $service->files->get($artwork_id, array('fields' => 'md5Checksum'));
```

Seems like the API returns a field only if you specify it.